# Some weebly features don't work when exporting to HTML and hosting on a different server

Tags: html, css, export, weebly

Recently I've been tasked with redesigning a website for the current company I'm working at. I've been using weebly to make the site, and then exporting the HTML to be re-hosted on the company's servers.

However, I've noticed that some functionality in weebly's code has stopped working. I imagine this might be due to weebly hosting some elements on their own servers, but this is merely a beginners best guess.

**1. The picture for the logo on the banner does not appear once the HTML is rehosted**

For comparison, here's the site while hosted on weebly:
http://mjmacoustique.weebly.com/

and the site on the company's servers:
http://www.mjm.qc.ca/redesign2015/

When weebly hosts, the ''MJM'' image should be on the top left and function as a return to home page button when clicked. However, when it's hosted on the company's server, the image is not found.

**2. On Firefox, the background image of the home page is replaced with an all black background**

When opened in firefox, it fails to load the background image of the main page.
Any help or solutions to these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with question #1: the logo is hosted on weebly's servers, but in the html it's written in a shortcut method like this example: /uploads/2/6/8/5/26851316/1434298489.png"

the easy workaround would be to keep the weebly version of the site working, in in the html change the src value of the missing images to something like this http://mjmacoustique.weebly.com/uploads/2/6/8/5/26851316/1434298489.png

So you haveto add the http://YOURSITE.weebly.com before all the src values of your images.

otherwise, just load all the images you need on a blank page of the site on your servers, copy image urls of those and replace the urls in the html with that.

Hope that helps?

The firefox issue might also be solved if all your src values are linked correctly but I cannot be sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried exporting a site from weebly, some assets were missing from the zip it produced.  This resulted in some images failing to appear because they simply weren't there.  I don't know how often this happens (or if it happens only for some sites), but weebly's export feature definitely seems to have bugs.

I worked around this by using wget to recursively fetch the content that weebly was hosting.  Then I hand-copied the missing assets (and only the missing assets) from the directory structure saved by wget and merged them into the directory structure from weebly's export zip.  This is time-consuming, but necessary since the directory structure fetched by wget includes dynamically-generated content (meta data for weebly's editor, assets with decorated names, etc) that you probably don't want in the content you host elsewhere.